# How to remove double quotes in csv with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuIFw.png)

Hi there, I have been dealing with something, but it didn't work whatever i tryed. In my csv file values are separated with double quotes. That's why, happened some problem. Csv file is not completely true.

I have been trying to scrape addresses in this page: https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#news

And also numbers are have to be unified. These values separated with comma. Like 99,341,447 but it's have to be 99341447
How can i fix this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

response = requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#news').content

soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')

tbody=soup.find('table', id='main_table_countries_today').find('tbody').find_all('tr')[8:11]

with open('corona1.csv','w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['countries','total_cases','total_deaths','total_recovered','active_cases','total_cases_in_1m','deaths_in_1m','population'])



    for value in tbody:
            countries = value.find_all('td')[1].text
            total_cases= value.find_all('td')[2].text
            total_deaths=value.find_all('td')[4].text
            total_recovered=value.find_all('td')[6].text
            active_cases=value.find_all('td')[8].text
            total_cases_in_1m=value.find_all('td')[10].text
            deaths_in_1m=value.find_all('td')[11].text
            population=value.find_all('td')[14].text


            csv_writer.writerow([countries,total_cases,total_deaths,total_recovered,active_cases,total_cases_in_1m,deaths_in_1m,population])
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the first issue, you must import `QUOTE_NONE` from `csv`:

```
from csv import QUOTE_NONE
```

Then, when you create `csv_writer`, you must specify the following additional arguments:

```
csv_writer = writer(csv_file, escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Regarding the second issue, characters in strings can be replaced like this:

```
total_cases_in_1m = value.find_all('td')[10].text.replace(",", "")
```